# javascript confirm alert not working when used with disable button code in asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform with a submit button like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSub" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClientClick="return processSub();" />
```

The javascript function it calls is like this

```
function processSub(){

    var btnId = '<%= btnSub.ClientID %>'

    var userSelection = confirm('Are you sure you wish to submit');
    if (userSelection){
         document.getElementById(btnId).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Now I want to disable the submit button when the user clicks submit. But when I call the code to set the attribute to disabled the submit doesn't happen.
When I comment this line `document.getElementById(btnId).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");` in the IF block, it works and continues with the submit.

Why is this so and how do I get it to work? I am not using any JavaScript library and don't want to as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no `OnClick` specified on the button, it will still do a form post (PostBack) when it is clicked. You set the `disabled` state with javascript, but immediately after a PostBack occurs therefore resetting the Button to it's original state.

if you want to disable the button you can set it in code begind after the user confirmes.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSub" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClientClick="return processSub();" 
    OnClick="btnSub_Click" />

protected void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //disable the button
    btnSub.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use code behind. The disable works client side with the code I have but when use that code to disable it doesn't do the submit. That is the problem.

Comment: when I comment out the disable the submit happens.

Comment: It is one or the other. After return true there will be a submit. You cannot prevent that by disabling the button first. Or return false in both cases.

Comment: THat is what I am saying. There is no submit after a return true after this line `document.getElementById(btnId).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");` When I comment that line the return true works and the submit happens.

Comment: Yes, and that is why you need to disable it (again) after a PostBack. Either in code behind or with jquery after the page is reloaded.

Comment: for the postback to happen the submit needs to happen first. That submit is not happening when I have this line `document.getElementById(btnId).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");` before the `return true`

Answer (score -1):

submit the form by js before return in if statement

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```